# Насколько принята такая практика?

Tags: база-данных

Доброго времени суток. У меня такой немного отвлеченный вопрос. Насколько является принятой такая практика когда разработчику не дают доступ к продакшн базе данных, а только к тестовой?

Ошибка воспроизводится только на тех данных которые есть только в продакшн базе. На тестовой базе не воспроизводится. Доступа к продакш нет. Что делать в этом случае?

Comment: разверните копию продакшн-базы в тестовой среде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если разработчик не понимает, что ему нечего делать на продакшн-базе - нафиг такого работника.

---

Надо различать два случая.

1. База на продакшне никоим образом не должна участвовать в процессе разработки. По-моему, это очевидно, и разработчику там делать нечего.
2. Если речь идёт о непредоставлении для разработке дампа реальной базы, то нужно понимать, что есть баги, которые воспроизводятся только при определённых наборах данных. Наверное, можно лечить их теоретически. Но по мне так разработчик имеет все основания закрыть такой багрепорт со статусом "Can not reproduce" и снять с себя всю ответственность за него.

Возможно, есть какие-то наглухо законспирированные структуры, которым тайна важней. Но лично мне за 20 с лишним лет ни разу не встречались настолько оголтелые конспираторы, которые сделали бы выбор в пользу глюков на продакшне. Хотя во некоторых случаях речь шла не только о коммерческой, но и о гостайне.

Так что во втором случае нужно исходить из конкретной ситуации. Например, упёртость начальника соотносить с размерами своей зарплаты на этом месте :)

Comment: Зависит как бы от работника, наверное :)

Comment: Ну да, некоторым это можно внушить :)

Comment: простой пример. Ошибка воспроизводится только на тех данных которые есть только в продакшн базе. На тестовой базе не воспроизводится. Доступа к продакш нет. Что делать в этом случае?

Comment: @JuniorThree в чем проблема добавить в тестовую БД часть значений из основной?

Comment: спросите об этом у моего начальника) Для него это табу)

Comment: @JuniorThree, Осмотреть поцЫента без препарирования или же пойти и доложить начальству. Оно не даёт, вот и пусть решает что теперь делать.

Comment: Само собой, тестовая база - это слепки с рабочей. Причём в максимально близком окружении, хотя бы на уровне ОС, версий mysql, библиотек и пр.

Comment: Да, для разработки доступ на продуктив не нужен.  Но для сопровождения - необходим. Особенно наивными выглядят желания работодателя оптимизировать работу с базой (подразумевая продуктив), когда у тебя доступ только на девелоперскую, где объём имеющихся данных на порядок меньше. Люди не понимают, что, например, на Оракле способ оптимизации запросов существенно зависит от объёма данных.

Answer (score 1):

> Насколько является принятой такая практика когда разработчику не дают доступ к продакшн базе данных, а только к тестовой?

Всегда не дают. Там приватные данные скорее всего.

> Ошибка воспроизводится только на тех данных которые есть только в продакшн базе. На тестовой базе не воспроизводится. Доступа к продакш нет. Что делать в этом случае?

Посмотреть на ошибку, подумать, чем она может быть вызвана. Полазить по коду по предполагаемой цепочке вызовов и посмотреть, где что-то может пойти не так.

Точно так же, как делалось, когда заказчики прислали баг, что на графиках не отображаются данные. Прислади они его в середине января. А ошибка была в том, что декабрь некорректно превращался в 0 вместо 12 и весь декабрь графики были пустыми, т. к. делалась выборка за 0 месяцев.

Comment: "*Там приватные данные скорее всего*" - и что? Разработчик, неважно в штате он или контрактник, в таком случае подписывает соглашение о неразглашении. В нормальных конторах по крайней мере.

Comment: Соглашение о неразглашении тут не при чём. Данные из реальной базы никто не даст. Дадут их же, но в обфусцированном виде, либо какое-то их подмножество. И да, на то что дадут распространяется соглашение о неразглашении.

Comment: "*Данные из реальной базы никто не даст*" - Хм.. А я и не знал, что столько лет с фейковыми или обфусцированными дампами работаю... Наверное, какая-то зараза их подменяет, пока они по 3306 порту птешествуют  :) Откуда у вас такие странные мысли-то берутся?

Comment: Оттуда, что серьёзные органицации никогда не давали. Может кто-то и даёт, но по-нормальному - нет.

Comment: То есть 25 лет я работаю в фигульках каких-то, ага... Или, может быть, вы говорите о каких-нибудь приходящих фрилансерах?

Comment: @klopp, нет, я говорю о нормальных организациях. Не знаю, с чем ты работаешь, может просто специфика такая. Но никто финансовую информацию в открытом виде давать совершенно не собирался. Как раз фрилансерам-то может и дадут доступ, если считать, что им вряд ли дадут что-то  критичное делать.

Comment: Ну так это частные проблемы взаимоотношений конкретного работодателя и конкретного работника. Делать из этого общее правило и глобальные выводы как минимум странно. "*Как раз фрилансерам-то может и дадут доступ*" - а штатным работникам, знапчит, не дадут. IMHO, это уже феерическая глупость, обсуждать которую я не вижу смысла.

Comment: @klopp, нет. И ты действительно считаешь, что, например банк, должен отдать полную базу счетов клиентов под подписку о неразгашении?

Comment: Во-первых, это решать банку, а не нам. Во-вторых, "*частные проблемы, из которых не нужно делать глобальных выводов*".